# curl as hyperlink in email by Jenkins workflow

Tags: curl, jenkins-workflow

I need to send below mentioned command as hyperlink in email from Jenkins workflow. Goal is, Recipient should click on hyperlink and this command should do action.

curl -x post JENKINS_URL/job_name/$BUILD_NUMBER/ACTION_TO_DO

Appreciate help !

Answer (score 0):

Not really a Jenkins question I suppose; more of a question about how to construct some HTML (or something) which popular mail clients would interpret by prompting you to run a command. Probably there is universal solution; for example a signed ActiveX control might work in Microsoft-provided mail clients. Or it may be possible to create a signed Java applet that would work in browser-based clients.